# VBA setting a Dim as "=RC[##]"

Tags: vba, excel

I've got column T filled with a formula which returns a double.  For example, T8 has the formula =S8/K8 (but that's not too important).

You can sort of understand the code by looking at it, but my issue comes from **`years = "=RC[14]"`** which returns a **Type mismatch** error.

```
Dim years As Double

For Each Cell In Range("$F$8:$F$" & lastrow)
    years = "=RC[14]"

    If years = 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No inventory"
    End If
    If years < 1 And years <> 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Less than a year's worth of inventory"
    End If
    If years > 1 Then
        If Int(years) = 1 Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No Activity Required - OH qty exceeds EAU 1 year"
        Else: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No Activity Required - OH qty exceeds EAU " & Int(years) & "years"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Also, I'm aware that my If-Else nests could be cleaner, but I'm not very experienced with VBA and this was a pretty simple way for me to do it.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

I now have to select the range of cells I want edited:

```
Range("$F$8:$F$" & lastrow).Select
For Each wCell In Range("$F$8:$F$" & lastrow)
    years = wCell.Offset(0, 14).Value                    
    If years = 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No inventory"
    End If
    If years < 1 And years <> 0 Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Less than a year's worth of inventory"
    End If
    If years > 1 Then
        If Int(years) = 1 Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No Activity Required - OH qty exceeds EAU 1 year"
        Else: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No Activity Required - OH qty exceeds EAU " & Int(years) & "years"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You're dim'ing years as a double, but then setting it to a string.  Are you just trying to set it to the value of a particular cell here?

Comment: @TMH8885 That is exactly what I'm trying to do.  Am I able to do something like 

Dim years As Range 

and then say 

years = RC[14].value ?  

Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can leave years as a double then set it equal to the value of that cell.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting a double to a string value. You need to reference your range using the Range object. To do relative referencing use the Offset function. Please don't use `Cell` as a variable name since that is a reserved word in Excel.

Modify accordingly:

```
Dim years As Double
Dim wCell As Range

For Each wCell In Range("$F$8:$F$" & lastrow)
    years = wCell.Offset(0,14).Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's very close!  Now I just have the issue of filling only one cell with that Offset value.  That is, I fill cell F8 with the value from T8.  So it runs like this: F8 = T8, F8 = T9, F8 = T10, etc...  How might I fix this?        I edited my original question for your bit here.

Comment: EDIT:  I got it.  I have to have a wCell.Select line in there.

Comment: You don't actually need to do a Select, you can just assign the value to where you want.